# How to parse strings safely?

Tags: java, string, security, parsing

We know that using string concatenation to form SQL queries renders a program vulnerable to SQL injection. I usually get around that by using parameter features provided by the API of whatever database software I'm using.

But I haven't heard of this being a problem in regular system programming. Consider the following code as part of a program that allows a user to write to files in his private directory only.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String directoryName = "Bob";
String filePath = null;
String text = "some text";

System.out.print("Enter a file to write to: ");
filePath = scanner.nextLine();

// Write to the file in Bob's personal directory for this program (i.e. Bob/textfile.txt)
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(directoryName + "/" + filePath);
file.write(text.getBytes());
```

Is the second-last line a vulnerability? If so, how can the program be made more secure (particularly in Java, C++ and C#)? One way is to validate input for escape characters. Anything else?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I think that's the term I was looking for. The Java official tutorials seem to suggest that prepared statements are special to SQL. Can they be applied in a generic context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution here is to have a whitelist of acceptable characters.  Modifying your original code (to include Java conventions, since you said you're new...)

```
package javawhitelist;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JavaWhiteListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String directoryName = "Bob"; 
        String filePath = null; 
        FileWriter stream = null;
        String text = "some text";  
        System.out.print("Enter a file to write to: "); 
        filePath = scanner.nextLine();  
        String WHITELIST = "[^0-9A-Za-z]+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(WHITELIST);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(filePath);

        //You need to do m.find() because m.matches() looks for COMPLETE match
        if(m.find()){ 
            //reject input.
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }else{
            // Write to the file in Bob's home directory (i.e. Bob/textfile.txt) 
            try{
                File toWrite = new File(directoryName + File.separator + filePath);

                if(toWrite.canWrite()){
                    stream = new FileWriter(toWrite);
                    stream.write(text);
                }   
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(stream != null){
                    stream.close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The default implementation of any JVM runs with all the access permissions of the user.  Using the `File.canWrite()` method will help ensure that the user won't write over a file he/she has no permission to.  The MOST secure solution (specifying EXACTLY where the file will go) would be to use 
`com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem.getName()` 
and use that to build the 
`/home/$USER` 
part of the directory name.  Some solutions might tell you to use 
`System.getProperty("user.home"):` 
or some such, but those rely upon easily changeable environment variables.

I tried to be thorough, I hope this helps.

Comment: That _was_ rather thorough indeed, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I've never used the Pattern and Matcher classes before so this is something for me to digest.

Being new to Java, and seeing that there's a class for almost every situation, I was hoping there would be a standard solution for filtering user input.

Comment: In any language I've ever worked with, user input validation has always been acheived using regex.  Solution 1 is always whitelist, solution 2 is blacklist.  
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Java_Project
For more Java-specific material.

Comment: Oh, and if my answer is the best among what you've seen here, feel free to click "accept."  (checkbox.)

Answer (score 3):

Any input from the user should be considered "**suspicious**"

In your case you are assuming that the file path is somewhere that the user is supposed to write.

The user can pass any filepath and modify (if the program has permissions) a file you did not expect.

So yes the line:

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(directoryName + "/" + filePath);
```

is indeed a vulnerability

This concept applies to C++ as well

Comment: Well the concept applies to absolutely any programming language ;)

Comment: Java typically runs with user permissions, so it should only be able to write where the user is allowed to. However, there is a very popular desktop OS out there that until recently defaulted to allowing users to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are several [reserved characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) in a filename you might want to search the path given by the user. You might also want to check that the string doesn't contain `../`, `:/` etc, which would let the user tamper with the "home directory" path. I would recommend using a regular expression to validate the given string before using it. If the validation fails simply abort the operation and let the user know something was wrong with the input instead of trying to fix it.

The file structure can be quite complex if one does not know what he's doing and characters is not the only problem, as mentioned in other answers. Which file names that are valid is different in the various file systems. Old FAT-system have a limitation of max 8 characters while newer NTFS used by Windows allow up to 255 characters.

Updated answer to give more clarity.

Comment: So I suppose a useful validation would be to check for slashes and backslashes and reject such input. Would escape characters like backspace also be a security risk? Is there some sort of input validation class in Java and C# that handles this in an elegant way?

Comment: And already we've got a security bug in your code. Because STARTING with `../` isn't enough. `foo/../../../privateStuff` is a perfectly fine path. So is `C:/Windows`.  And depending on how you fix it (just replace `../` with nothing?) you get other problems, eg. `..././doh`. Then there are things like ADS on NTFS (no idea if java allows that though?) and so on. So really the best idea is to NOT fix it yourself.

Comment: Actually I didn't propose to fix the problem but rather let the user know if the validation failed. And of course, checking the beginning of the string isn't enough; my bad.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite different from a SQL injection problem.  In a SQL injection problem, maliciously entered parameters can be used to execute commands in a privileged security context, because the *database* user under which the commands are executed typically has carte blanche access to write to rows in the database.

In the example that you provided, the key question is "as what user will the Java code be executed?".  If you're executing this code as, for example, a CGI script, then any file or directory that the Web Server process' user can write to is vulnerable. If you're simply running this from the command-line, it's really up to the Operating System (and not the Java code) to protect the files/directories that the user is not supposed to be able to write to.

If your intent is to only allow the code to write to the user's directory, then the other answers provided are correct.  However, I can envision many scenarios in which this might not be the case.  e.g. Perhaps you're writing some code to automatically edit a file in the /etc directory.

In a nutshell, you want to consider the context in which your code will be executed, and what security will be provided by that context, and what security you will need to provide within your own code within that context.

PS - You usually don't want to assume that "/" is your directory separator.  Java provides the *File.separator* constant for this purpose.

Comment: `File.separator` is the technically correct way to specify the file separator. However, the I/O layer will automatically change / and \ to be correct for the underlying platform. This is more of a style issue though, I also prefer `File.separator`.

Answer (score 2):

If you see code like that, run.

Some issues:

Directory traversal attacks: Traditionally, file systems confuse UI and API. We've got this language with file paths but no way to state particularly names cleanly. On typical opersating systems `..` will allow moving up the directory structure (not necessarily at the start of the path). Note also that more than one character may function as a directory separator.

Links: File system links within the directory may link elsewhere.

NUL characters: If you attempt to specify a suffix, as a file extension for instance, a zero byte will truncate the path.

Shell escapes: You might find issues with shell code that attempts to interpret the file path, either before creation or coming along later.

Existing files: If the file exists, what happens?

Disc usage: If the data is user supplied, are you checking that it isn't huge?

So, try to avoiding using outsider created file names. If you really have to, I suggest applying a tight whitelist of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can get user directory with `System.getProperty("user.home")`. If your program runs under that user, and users rights are managed correctly, then no problems expected. Also you can get path separator character with another property - `file.separator`. And, finally, there are methods `File.canRead()` and `File.canWrite()`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. But actually I wasn't talking about OS-created user directories. I am making a little program where if you login as Bob, all data pertaining to Bob is stored in C:\SomeFolder\Bob\ so I can't enjoy the rights management features provided by the OS.

Comment: Then, use regular expressions for file names. http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=file+name

Comment: That website looks like a VERY useful one. During all the years I had to deal with regexp I wish I had come across that one. Thank you.

Comment: I was just to lazy, to write a regex for file name by my own now :)